# Calling C# Code behind code from Java Script

Tags: c#, javascript

We are using VS2008. We are calling ActiveX shell scrip object which is created as EXE executable, which reads the Pinpad for authentication and returns the result.  This object is called in Javascript in ASPX page.

After getting the result we need to store the information, which we have written in C# code behind page.

My question is, how we should call the code behind or a WCF service in ASPX java script.

my java script code is as follows:

```
  function launchExecutable(strdata) {

        try {
            var shellActiveXObject = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");

            shellActiveXObject.Run("c:\\Test\\EBCK.exe " + strdata, 1, true);
        }
        catch (e) {
            alert(e.message);
        }

        try {
            var abc = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
            // from here we have to call the C# code which is written in CS file or 
            // call a WCF Web service
        }
        catch (e) {
            alert(e.message);
        }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

To call the wcf service in javascript make use of the ScriptManager. For example:

```
<asp:scriptmanager id="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        <services>
            <asp:servicereference path="http://localhost:61586/Service1.svc">        
 </services>
```

In the above code, note that the servicereference  is set to the WCF service hosted on another domain.

use makeCall:

```
function makeCall() {
                      var proxy = new JsonpAjaxService.Service1();
                     proxy.set_enableJsonp(true);
                     proxy.GetCustomer(onSuccess, onFail, null);
                 }
```

you can use **onSuccess** to get the result from the service call and display the data.

```
function onSuccess(result) {
                 alert( result.Name + " " +result.Address);
             }
```

and you can use **onFail** if the servide fails.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the value in hidden field and postback the page. Access the hidden field value in code behind when the page is posted back.

```
<asp:Hidden Id="hid" value="" runat="server">
```

To postback the page in javascript use __doPostback.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a script manager onto your page

and create a static method with the `[webmethod]` attribute and call that method from JQuery or javascript